# get request body from WebResourceRequest

Tags: android, webresourcerequest

Is there anyway to get the request body from WebResourceRequest? I did run into a few other SO posts with no solution. Has anything changed from then?

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView, android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest))